# Python3 variable increment and assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing this Fibonacci generator function in python3:

```
def fibo(n):
    a = b = 1

    for i in range(n): 
        yield a
        a,b = b,a + b

for x in fibo(10):
    print(x)
```

Above code gives:
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55

But,

```
def fibo(n):
    a = b = 1

    for i in range(n): 
        yield a
        a = b
        b = a + b

for x in fibo(10):
    print(x)
```

the above code gives:1
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256

Only difference is assigning `b` to `a` and `a+b` to `b` is happening on the same line in first code. How is this affecting the output?

Comment: You do realise that ``a = b`` affects the value of ``a`` in ``b = a + b``? Whereas in ``a, b = b, a + b`` the value of ``a`` is changed *after* evaluating ``a + b``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Why does the value of a change after evaluation of a+b? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second code sample the two lines

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

have the following effect:

1. Assign `b` to `a`
2. Assign `a+b` to `b`, which, since a equals b, is the same as assigning `b+b` to `b` (or, doubling `b`)

So, the effect is that each yield is double the previous one, which you have shown with the sample output.

In the first example you are using tuple packing to assign both a and b at once, and everything on the right side of the `=` is evaluated before every assignment.

Comment: "everything on the right side of the = is evaluated before every assignment" - this is what I was not aware of. Thanks a lot.